# Load .csv files from folder

Tags: stata

I have a folder with .csv files, total size 6 GB.
I want to insert all my data from this folder in Stata, automatically.

Searching the net, I have found some solutions, like:

```
cd "E:\myfolder"

. insheet using "file1.csv"

. save "a", replace


. local satafiles: dir . files "*.csv"

. foreach file of local satafiles {
  2. append using "a"
  3. save "myfile.dta", replace
  4. }
```

But if I explore the imported data, I have the same date value in all entries.
Does anyone have experience in Stata import of data?

Comment: "a" just calls the string a; replace the first quote by a back tick, and the second one by a tick (I can't show it due to Markdown syntax). Add double quotes around that to protect the strings in case file paths have spaces. More in `help local`.

Answer (score 3):

It's repeating because you are just appending "a", i.e. your first dataset, multiple times. Try this:

```
cd "E:\myfolder"

clear
local satafiles: dir . files "*.csv"

foreach file of local satafiles {
    preserve
    insheet using `file',clear
    save temp,replace
    restore
    append using temp
}
*remove the temporary .dta file
rm temp

save alldata, replace
```

Note that if the files are becoming too large you can do some space-saving formatting after the `insheet` command.

Comment: There is a one line code for Stata data : `fornumlist 1/100:append using "E:\myfolder\mydata\fileX.dta"` . But, I am surprised this doesn't work for csv file